# Solving a function and getting the roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$x^2+y^2=4y $$

$$x^2 + y^2 - 4y = 0$$

$$x ^2 + (y-2)^2 = 4$$

Then I get the radius being  $$(0,2)$$ and the range is $$0<=y<=4$$

Why is $y$ here ranges from 0 to 4?

[image]

Comment: This is not legible.  Please type the question.

Comment: Please give a clear picture or write it using Latex(if possible).

Comment: The center is $(0,2)$ the radius is $2.$ The extreme values for y then are $0$ at one extreme and $4$ at the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, the given equation 
$$x^2+y^2=4y$$
At,$x=0$,
$$y^2-4y=0$$
$$\implies y(y-4)=0$$
Hence,y=0,4.
So the points are (0,0),(0,4)

And if $y>4~or~y<0$ that yields $x^2<0$ which is not possible,because square of any number can't be negative.

Comment: Ahh my bad, I missed changing $x = 0$ Thanks soo much!!

Answer (score 1):

If $y>4$ or $y<0$, then $(y-2)^2 > 4$. Then, $x^2 < 0$, which cannot be satisfied by any $x\in\mathbb R$.

In other words, the set of all solutions is such that $y\in[0,4]$, as it is not possible to have a solution with $y<0$ or $y>4$.